# UnsatisfiedDependencyException by Maven Packed war but not Intellij IDE why?

Tags: maven, package, war, c3p0

i am using Intellij IDE for my springboot project, while running my spring boot project it works fine. but when i create a war with mvn package and run with java -jar project.war it throwing the following error

### Warning

2018-05-23 11:05:08.635  WARN 13025 --- [           main] 
 ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered 
 during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
 Error creating bean with name HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': 
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
 nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
 creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource 
 [com/myproject/config/DefaultDataSource.class]: Bean instantiation via 
 factory method failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to 
 instantiate [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Factory method 
 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is 
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

### Exception

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration 
        report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
        2018-05-23 11:05:10.854 ERROR 13025 --- [           main] 
        o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
        Error creating bean with name 
       'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/myproject/config/DefaultDataSource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

### Code

```
 @Configuration
    public class DefaultDataSource {
    @Autowired
    DataBaseCreds dataBaseCreds;
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass(dataBaseCreds.getDB_DRIVER());
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        }
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(dataBaseCreds.getDB_URL());
        dataSource.setUser(dataBaseCreds.getDB_USERNAME());
        dataSource.setPassword(dataBaseCreds.getDB_PASSWORD());
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(200);
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

Comment: it'd be nice to no more about the nested `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Comment: Sorry guys my mistake there were two versions of c3p0 libraries packed war file /WEB-INF/lib removed one works like charm  - Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys my mistake there were two versions of c3p0 libraries packed war file /WEB-INF/lib removed one works like charm - Thanks for reading